# JavaScript promise bypassed resolve and proceed to .then()

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I was having some problem with nested promise which resulting in forgotten promise problem.

```
let promiseList = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //first query to retrieve from firebase
        query.once( 'value', data => {
            var promises = [];

            data.forEach(snapshot => {
                //get item key

                //second query based on item key                                    
                var promise = query.once('value');
                promises.push(promise);

                promise.then(data => { 
                    var itemDetail = data.val();

                    var receiptID = itemDetail.receiptID;
                    // third query to find matching receiptID
                    var query = firebase.database().ref('receipts');
                    query.once('value', data => {   
                        data.forEach(snapshot => {

                            snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                                if(childSnapshot.key == receiptID){
                                    var branchDetail = childSnapshot.val().branch;
                                    var branchName = branchDetail.branchName;

                                    //console.log('inside promise ' + branchName);
                                    datasetarr.push({branchName: branchName});
                                }
                            });

                        });
                    }); 

                });
            }); 

            // wait till all promises are finished then resolve the result array
            Promise.all(promises).then(() => resolve(datasetarr)); 
        });             
    });

// print out array here
promiseList.then((arr) => {
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log(arr[i].branchName);
}   
});
```

I managed to print out the data from the console.log with 'inside promise'. However, when I tried to print it out from the .then(), there is nothing shown.

The problem now is it actually ran the .then() first before I resolve the promise.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why all the nesting? It's totally unnecessary.

Comment: have you tried to use `promises.push(promise)` after `.then()` ?

Comment: What I am trying to do is firstly get a list of receipt items. Then for each receipt item, I get its details like receiptID. Then I proceed to find the branch details based on receiptID. With these, it leads me to nested promises. I not sure how to actually separate them

Comment: @CameloCatafarno You mean put it after .then()? But I thought you should push it into array first?

Comment: you pushed it to an array, then chained further on it without passing the new promise that .then creates to the array. (only one of the two need to be passed.) additionally, nothing was returned to the .then, so it's not gonna wait on what was inside it to complete.

Comment: @KevinB Hmm so how do I fix it if that's the case

Comment: @EmmaHannah turned my not-answer into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Firebase, but I do know promises.
Check this sample chaining promises, notice the `return` statements which produce the chaining.

```
var outerPromise = query.once('value').then(data => {
    // Promise array to group 2nd level promises and then do a Promise.all.
    var promises = [];
    // This will be the main output of the outerPromise.
    // We will populate it asynchronously inside our 2nd level promises.
    var datasetarr = [];
    data.forEach(snapshot => {
        // 2nd level promises, will be appended to the promises array.    
        // and will be enchained with the 3d level promise.
        var promise = query.once('value').then(data => { 
            var itemDetail = data.val();
            var receiptID = itemDetail.receiptID;
            var query = firebase.database().ref('receipts');
            // Third level promise. It's enchained by the return statement.
            return query.once('value').then(data => {   
                data.forEach(snapshot => {
                    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                        if(childSnapshot.key == receiptID){
                            var branchDetail = childSnapshot.val().branch;
                            var branchName = branchDetail.branchName;

                            //console.log('inside promise ' + branchName);
                            datasetarr.push({branchName: branchName});
                        }
                    });
                });
            }); 
        });
        promises.push(promise);
    }); 

    // We wait until 2nd (and third) level promises are ready
    // and the return our desired output, the datasetarr
    return Promise.all(promises).then(()=> datasetarr);
});             

// Since it's all chained, the outerPromise will resolve once all promises are completed
// and we can get the output we supplied in the last chaining.
outerPromise.then((arr) => {
    console.log(arr)  
});
```

Comment: Nope that does not work. Still nothing printed out from the console.log at .then()

Comment: @EmmaHannah, check the edit. Btw, you should read something about [promise chaining in order to understand how it works](https://bitsofco.de/javascript-promises-101/).

Comment: Thanks it works! Let me try to understand how it works.

Comment: So basically you created an outerPromise to wrap all other promises inside. Then when you loop through each itemKey, you created a list of promises to get its details and branch details. After that, you added them to a promise array. Wait a minute, I think I am basically reading off the code. Do you mind to elaborate some explanation?

Comment: Let's say I have the 4th level of promise in this case, can I just do another query and put a return statement like the third level one in this case?

Comment: Yeah, but take into account the loop. You'll have to do the same we did for the 2nd level.

Comment: @LeonardoChaia Hey sorry to trouble you again! But let's say from the third level promise, I need to get the receiptID and query another account table. How can I achieve that? Can I just declare a new promise to query from firebase, then push the promise into promises array within the return of third level promise?

Comment: Hey @EmmaHannah, sorry for the delay. Hope you've solved it.

Comment: Hey sorry I realized that there were some logic problem with my code and the promise went broken. https://pastebin.com/6yEQCR1W What I tried to do is from the solution above, right after I get the receipt details, I make another promise to query for account details. Then, I push them to array and perform some duplicate filter in the .then(). But right now, the code just ran .then() without waiting the promise to resolve. Do you have any ideas to do this? If so, I can open a new thread

Answer (score 0):

That's not how promises work, there's seldom if ever a need to nest them. If `query.once` already returns a promise that's great, but otherwise you'll need to wrap it:

```
let returnsPromise = value => new Promise(res => query.once(value, data => res(data));
```

Again, if it already returns a promise that's unnecessary, but I'm not a firebase guy. At any rate, now you can do something like this:

```
let result = returnsPromise('value')
  // run secondary query based on item key
  .then(data => Promise.all(data.map(item => returnsPromise(item.key)))
  // now do stuff with those results
  .then(data => {
    return Promise.all(data.map(item => {
      let receiptID = item.val().receiptID;
      // Note that the same 'wrap if not already returning promise
      // idea' is applicable here, but for illustration I'm just
      // going to act like this returns a promise.
      // Also note that while I've been rather down on nesting
      // its more or less necessary here because you need to capture
      // the receipt ID from the surrounding scope.
      return firebase.database().ref('receipts')
        .once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {
          return snapshot
            .filter(x => x.key === receiptID)
            .map(x => {
              let branch = x.val().branch.branchName;
              return {branch: branch};
            });
        });
  }))
  // Now we have an array of arrays of results but we want to
  // remove the nesting.
  .then(arrayOfArrays => arrayOfArrays.reduce((x,y) => { return x.concat(y); }, []));
```

Now you have a result promise that contains the array of values. You can call `then` on it and iterate over it:

```
result.then(arr => arr.forEach(x => console.log(x.branchName)));
```

Comment: Why DV? Please explain.

Comment: Nope me DV. I not sure for another guy either. Somehow all the answers get downvoted.

Comment: @EmmaHannah at any rate, a good rule of thumb is to not nest: that's one of the problems promises were supposed to solve. Remember that as Leonardo Chaia points out returning a value inside a `then` returns a promise of that value. Also remember that you can return an array and then work with it in the next step in the chain. Another good rule of thumb is not to do too much in any one step in the chain, makes testing and debugging harder.

Comment: @JaredSmith Cool thanks soooooooo much for the helps! But what does the .map and .filter do? To map relevant data together and filter uneccessary data?

Comment: @EmmaHannah map takes a function and returns the result of applying it to each element of an array. Filter takes a function and keeps the items in the array the function returns true for.